# Rails: Not requiring js files to load on homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a rails application and the homepage is mostly a static page with some jquery. Once the user logs in there are other javascript files that are being used.

However, when I load the homepage I can see that all the js files are being loaded.

Is there a way not to load them? Should I remove `//= require_tree .` from `application.js` and somehow load them only when they are needed on other pages? I guess that should improve the loading time and Google pagespeed insights.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `//= require_tree .` would stop loading all js in the tree.  However, we have no idea what "the home page" is or what the rest of your application will need the js for.  If you have a controller end point i.e. `HomeController#index` you might just wanna use a different layout for that controller/action and omit the `//= require_tree` from that layout. Create a separate layout file, you could copy `application.html.erb` to `views/layouts/home.html.erb` for example and omit the line

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Then something like this in the controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout 'home'
end
```

Comment: I managed to do it, it made a bit of a mess on other pages but I can work from here. Thanks!

Comment: Why did it make a mess?  Suggestion was to use a seperate layout only for that controller action so that it wouldn't affect loading of js / assets on any other controller actions.